# Are there any built-in sounds that can be used while developing metro-style apps?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

Are there any built-in sounds that can be used while developing metro-style apps? I need to play some simple sounds like a click or coin-tossing etc. Am I required to add a mp3 file to my app, or are there some simple sounds that can be used out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find any way to play "system" sounds from a WinRT app. There is one minor exception, which you can control what sound is played when a Toast appears.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761492.aspx

Other than that, I don't believe it's possible.